# BLAS: Failed to load implementation from: com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeSystemBLAS - Centos 7

Tags: python, linux, apache-spark, blas

Minimium steps to reproduce:(CentOS 7)

```
scala> import com.github.fommil.netlib.BLAS
import com.github.fommil.netlib.BLAS

scala> println(BLAS.getInstance().getClass().getName())
22/07/03 20:09:42 WARN BLAS: Failed to load implementation from: com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeSystemBLAS
22/07/03 20:09:42 WARN BLAS: Failed to load implementation from: com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeRefBLAS
com.github.fommil.netlib.F2jBLAS
```

What I have done. Built [openBlas from source.](https://gist.github.com/dusenberrymw/d24fcefcd245cfacbc60d3b4caccc560)
Linked the libraries:

```
ln -sf /opt/OpenBLAS/lib/libopenblas.so /opt/OpenBLAS/lib/libblas.so
ln -sf /opt/OpenBLAS/lib/libopenblas.so /opt/OpenBLAS/lib/libblas.so.3
ln -sf /opt/OpenBLAS/lib/libopenblas.so /opt/OpenBLAS/lib/liblapack.so
ln -sf /opt/OpenBLAS/lib/libopenblas.so /opt/OpenBLAS/lib/liblapack.so.3
ln -sf /opt/OpenBLAS/lib/libopenblas.so /usr/lib64/libblas.so
ln -sf /opt/OpenBLAS/lib/libopenblas.so /usr/lib64/libblas.so.3
ln -sf /opt/OpenBLAS/lib/libopenblas.so /usr/lib64/liblapack.so
ln -sf /opt/OpenBLAS/lib/libopenblas.so /usr/lib64/liblapack.so.3
```

updated ld.conf:

```
include ld.so.conf.d/*.conf
/usr/local/lib
/usr/lib64
/opt/OpenBLAS/lib
```

Ran `ldconfig`.
Set LD_LIBRARY_PATH

```
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib64:/opt/OpenBLAS/lib
```

Tried passing the [lib with -D parameter](https://github.com/luhenry/netlib):

```
spark-shell --conf 'spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Ddev.ludovic.netlib.blas.nativeLib=libopenblas.so' --conf 'spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Ddev.ludovic.netlib.blas.nativeLib=libopenblas.so' --conf 'spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Ddev.ludovic.netlib.blas.nativeLibPath=/opt/OpenBLAS/lib/' --conf 'spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Ddev.ludovic.netlib.blas.nativeLibPath=/opt/OpenBLAS/lib/'
```

Add libs to alternatives:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config libblas.so
sudo update-alternatives --config libblas.so.3
sudo update-alternatives --config liblapack.so
sudo update-alternatives --config liblapack.so.3
```

Answer (score 1):

I was using a mix of old documentation and new documentation.

`spark-shell --conf 'spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Ddev.ludovic.netlib.blas.nativeLib=libopenblas.so' --conf 'spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Ddev.ludovic.netlib.blas.nativeLib=libopenblas.so' --conf 'spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Ddev.ludovic.netlib.blas.nativeLibPath=/opt/OpenBLAS/lib/libopenblas.so' --conf 'spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Ddev.ludovic.netlib.blas.nativeLibPath=/opt/OpenBLAS/lib/libopenblas.so'`

This worked for me with:

```
scala> import dev.ludovic.netlib.NativeBLAS
scala> NativeBLAS.getInstance()
res0: dev.ludovic.netlib.NativeBLAS = dev.ludovic.netlib.blas.JNIBLAS@de4bee9
```

Spark 3.2 migrated to using ludovic over fommil.